# Calculate rolling standard deviation using ave()

Tags: r

Say I have three columns and a value:

```
col1   col2   col3   val
  a     1       a     10
  a     1       a      3
  a     1       a      2
  a     1       a      4
  a     1       a      6
  b     1       a     20
  b     1       a     30
  b     5       a     100
  b     5       a     200
  b     5       a     100
  b     5       a     250
  b     5       a     180
```

Data are all sorted properly.  I need to add a rolling standard deviation over a given window `n` for each distinct group.  This would yield:

```
n = 3
col1   col2   col3   val   sd
  a     1       a     10   4.3
  a     1       a      3   1
  a     1       a      2   2
  a     1       a      4   NULL
  a     1       a      6   NULL
  b     1       a     20   NULL
  b     1       a     30   NULL
  b     5       a     100  57.7
  b     5       a     120  76.3
  b     5       a     200  70
  b     5       a     100  NULL
  b     5       a     250  NULL
```

*NOTE:  Those are just made up standard deviations, I didn't do the actual calcs.*

I tried using something like:

```
ave(tt$val, tt[, 1:3], FUN=function(x) rollapply(x, width = 3, align = 'left', FUN = sd))
```

This didn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, i just made up the sd numbers!  It's just a standard deviation.

Comment: ok fixed it with vals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a perfect job for `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(tt)[, sd := rollapply(val, width = 3, align = 'left', FUN = sd, fill = NA), by = list(col1, col2, col3)]
tt
    col1 col2 col3 val        sd
 1:    a    1    a  10  4.358899
 2:    a    1    a   3  1.000000
 3:    a    1    a   2  2.000000
 4:    a    1    a   4        NA
 5:    a    1    a   6        NA
 6:    b    1    a  20        NA
 7:    b    1    a  30        NA
 8:    b    5    a 100 57.735027
 9:    b    5    a 200 76.376262
10:    b    5    a 100 75.055535
11:    b    5    a 250        NA
12:    b    5    a 180        NA
```

Comment: This makes sense!  However, when I run it, it seems to work but then the sd is not stored when I view the data table.  Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: @JeffreyKramer, that doesn't make any sense. If you type `tt` in console it will show you what you need. Unless you adopted this code to your original data and made some mistake? maybe you did `sd = ` insted of `sd := `?

Comment: So bizarre.  It works with the dummy data but not on my real stuff.  Oh well, the concept works, so the problem is something else I'm doing.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyKramer, maybe provide a `head(dput(data), 100)` where `data` is your real data

Comment: I see what's causing the problem.  One of the columns is a Date type.  It works great when I replace it with dummies.  I'll figure out how to handle the date!

Comment: `data.table` has it's own date utility functions that can be embedded inside the code. See `?IDate`